# What are the important log/error files in ITIM 5.1?

Tags: tivoli-identity-manager

I want to know what are the important files in (DB2, TDS, WAS, TDI, TIM) which we need to be aware of and there uses.

Comment: Asking every sample question on Stack Overflow is not the suggested way to prepare yourself for the certification exams.

Answer (score 0):

Though all the files are important and serves its purpose, i have listed few based on initial go to. In case of ITIM the important files would be enrole property files found inside itim installed directory \ data directory. This is where  the connection properties, logging properties are all defined.

In case of TDS, the schema file ibmslapd.conf and those files found under etc folder are most important.

In case of TDI only the config file is important and for all these components 
the log files are important to debug. TIM - trace /msg log. TDS ibmslapd.log and TDI - ibmdi.log and WAS - Systemout.log